# gae unit testing hrd datastore inconsistency

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
facade.vote(datastoreRecordId, userId);
try{
    facade.vote(datastoreRecordId, userId);
    fail(); // Expect runtimeexception because voting twice is not allowed
} catch (RuntimeException ex) {}

hasVoted = facade.hasVoted(datastoreRecordId, userId);
```

I have a Unit Test, testing the facade to my gae server.
The Server is running on localhost, the datastore is wiped everytime in the setup method.

I put an Entity into the Datastore, then i basically check if it was persisted correctly! Sometimes it tells me that the Record was found and sometimes it tells me it was not found. (So hasVoted is true sometimes and sometimes false, sometimes the expected runtimeexception is thrown and sometimes not)

I tried using global transactions, synchronized locally and serverside and tried a single threaded HttpClient. I even put some sleeps between the calls to my facade. I also tried the threading switch in appengine.xml.

I have made a method where i run the test 100 times in a row, sometimes it works, sometimes the assert fails after 4 runs sometimes after 7, (16 is the record wohoo) its totally random. I just cant find out what the issue is. When i run the tests on my remote appengine instance, everything works fine, even if i run it 100 times in a loop. Any ideas except format c:?

Alright i found the issue, i disabled the HRD and moved to Master/Slave locally, now everything works as expected! Maybe this post can help someone in the future. Anyone understands this behaviour of HRD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HRD is ["eventually consistent"](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/hr/), meaning that when you write an entity it happens asynchronously: write method returns before data is actually persisted in Datastore. So if you query for an entity right after write, you might not find it.

Why this happens? It takes sometime for the Datastore to persist it and create indexes - read about [Life of a Datastore Write](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write.html).

Note: HRD's "eventual consistency" only affects queries. If you `put()` and then `get()` you should always get the entity.

So, the problems you are seeing should only happen if you used queries. Also, this problem should also be present on production servers (but you might not encounter it under test setup).

Comment: under production i have set up master/slave :) and yes it was a query. thanks peter!